# dataTables save position in table

Tags: datatables

I have a dataTables table (http://communitychessclub.com/examine.php) of chess games (players, event, result, etc.) and the user can click on the row and up pops the game moves. But I want the user to be able to then press the back button and be returned to the row in the previous table from where the link to the current game was.

Any ideas?

My script init:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTable.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.2/css/scroller.dataTables.min.css" />
<script async onload="myInit()" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script async onload="myInit()" src="//cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.2/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#cccr').DataTable( {

"createdRow": function(row, data, index) {$(row).attr('game', data.game);},

"search": {"search": "<?php echo ($_GET['player']); ?>"},

"deferRender": true,
"oSearch": {"sSearch": "<?php echo ($_GET['player']); ?>"},
"aaSorting": [],
"bPaginate": true,
"bLengthChange": true,
"bFilter": true,
"bSort": true,
"bInfo": true,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
//"sScrollY": "24.15rem",
"responsive": true,
"bAutoWidth":true,
"autoWidth": true,
"stateSave": true,
"ajax": "assets/games.ajax",

"columns": [

{ "data": "Date", "width": "7rem", },
{ "data": "Event" },
{ "data": "ECO" },
{ "data": "White" },
{ "data": "WhiteElo" },
{ "data": "Black" },
{ "data": "BlackElo" },
{ "data": "Result" },
{ "data": "game", visible : false }
]

} );

$("#cccr").on("click", "tr", function() {
window.location.href = 'basic.php?game='+$(this).attr('game');
} );
} );

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using this really rather cool [extension](https://github.com/jhyland87/DataTables-Keep-Conditions). It should allow you to return to the same place you left. Alternatively you could always move the moves detail into a modal dialog...?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, on page unload or in your on click action, grab the y position of the cursor.  Save that in local/session storage and on return to the page, grab the value and move to that position.